# How to convert proxyclass to xml right away

Tags: xml, wsdl

Hi I'm doing a webservice project.

and I need to convert proxyclass, which comes as a result from the webservice according to WSDL, to XML.

Actually the response is made as a XML file in the firstplace.
and when it comes to client, it converts to Proxyclass.

so is there any API for converting proxyclass to xml?

also I want to know if there's a way that client can get a XML file which is made from the server in the firstplace before it converts to proxyclass.

Comment: What language are you using for the client?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the proxy class to XML?

Comment: The Util that I'm trying to use accepts XML. So I need to convert the proxy class in order to use the util and proceed the Project.